# Add another data base connection in nopcommerce plugin?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I want to connect to another data base in nopcommerce.
It is possible to do with inside the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible, you can add database tables when you override the install method at your plugin base class.

Comment: @user1348351 was asking about connection to different DB. Not about how to add tables in current DB.